# using the python keyboard does not work when made into an EXE.

Tags: python, keyboard, pyinstaller

I have been working on a program that remaps certain keys on a connected keyboard. Everything works when I run the script from either idle or sublime. However, after I use pyinstaller nothing works. It still has the process running when I check task manager but the actual remapping does not work. Here is part of the code.

```
import keyboard

while True:
   keyboard.remap_key ('a','m')
```

Comment: Is the lib keyboard still with the exe?

Comment: Also if pyInstaller doesn't work you can also try using py2exe if you haven't already.  you can find how to use that here: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial

Comment: I tried two ways one with the --onefile and without. Both do not work. I am trying py2exe. Will let you know.

Comment: Alright, thanks for checking back about it. If it still doesn't work I will be glad to help you farther.

Comment: Hi, it still doesn't work. It seems there is a problem getting this module to run as an executable. Here is the output from the command window.

Comment: Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "threading.pyc", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
  File "threading.pyc", line 754, in run
  File "keyboard\__init__.pyc", line 292, in listen
  File "keyboard\_winkeyboard.pyc", line 560, in listen
  File "keyboard\_winkeyboard.pyc", line 553, in prepare_intercept
ArgumentError: argument 3: <type 'exceptions.OverflowError'>: long int too long to convert

Comment: Hm Alright, Ill look into this issue more! sorry for a 20 minute late response as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate the help.

Comment: I tried running the exe on a number of different environments. Windows 7, 8 and 10. No luck. Even running the file as administrator does not help. That said the script running from idle works in all environments. As this script changes the key bindings I am not sure if the default windows keyboard driver is overriding this when run as a exe. Has anyone else has any similar experience with this? Perhaps with different modules?

Comment: From what I know, windows shouldn't over-riding it. This is definitely interesting